# Why Laravel 5.1 removed the default authentication views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel and was just testing the authentication part of Laravel 5.1. And I got "View [auth.login] not found." error when I was accessing "/auth/login". It looks like the authentication view is not there as it is supposed to be.

How can I get it back? Should I try 5.0 instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since Laravel 5 auth views, assets and routes was removed. The arrival
>   of version 5.1 has seen the disappearance of these items after many
>   discussions ...

when you install laravel 5.1 you will only get the home page (welcome.blade.php). In order to get authentication stuff back install this package :

[Scafold](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold)

**Laravel 5.1** is a **LTS** release which means a long term support, bug fixes for 2 years and security fixes for 3 years ... so it's recommended to use 5.1 instead of 5.